# How to creating auto_increment columns in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench to create my DB tables. I have a table called `Movies`. Among its fields is one called `purchase_times` which is meant to record the total number of times a movie has been purchased. So, it should auto increment whenever a particular movie is purchased, but it isn't the primary key in the table. I want the column to read zero when no one has purchased the movie, then change to 1 when the first person purchases it, then keep incrementing as more purchases of the movie are made.

Q1. Is it possible to have two fields with auto-increment in the same table?

Q2. How can I set the value of the said column to be zero by default i.e before the movie is purchased by anyone?

Here is what I did:

```
CREATE TABLE Movies (
  movie_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  genre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  release_year INT(11) NOT NULL,
  description TEXT(200) NOT NULL,
  poster_url VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  purchase_times INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id)
);
```

Comment: An Auto_increment is a column that automatocally increases when you add a new row, so there will be one one allowed.

Comment: You might consider that a movie can belong to multiple genres, in which case genre would belong in a separate table, and with yet another table to relate movies and genres.

Comment: Thanks. I have a separate table for genre already and one for purchased items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Yes, It's possible. But, If you have two `auto_increment` columns they would be the same, so there is no point having two auto_increment columns.

Q2. You can follow this query to set 0 default.

```
CREATE TABLE Movies (
  movie_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  genre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  release_year INT(11) NOT NULL,
  description TEXT(200) NOT NULL,
  poster_url VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  purchase_times INT(11) DEFAULT '0', //here is the zero default
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That was helpful. 

I'm thinking that instead of having that column for purchase_times, I can have a separate table (purchases) for recording purchased movies/series, then have movie/series id as foreign keys in that table, then using the COUNT function, I can query for the number of times that a particular movie/series has been purchased. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks very much. That was helpful.

Comment: If it's really help full. Give it a tick, sir.

Comment: Oook a tick. Now I just did. Still under orientation on this platform.